# How to pause a layer in cocos2d 2.0

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a Scene that contains a GamePlay layer and an HUDLayer which contains my pause menu.  I was wondering if there was anyway to pause just one layer in a scene so that I can pause the GamePlay layer but still access and click inside the pause menu in my HUDLayer.  I tried using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
```

but that pauses everything and doesn't accept touches in my pause menu.  If there is no way to pause a single layer, what is the best way to incorporate a pause menu into a game? Thanks.

P.S. I am using the most recent version of cocos2d which is cocos2d 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://timroadley.com/2011/11/21/game-template-part-9-adding-pause-resume-exit/) tutorial should help.
But basically what you wanna do is unschedule your scene then on resume reschedule it.
Here is what I did in my HUD layer.

```
-(void)pause:(id)sender
{
    if(paused)
    {
        [gamescene scheduleUpdate];
    }
    else {
        [gamescene unscheduleUpdate];
    }
    paused =!paused;
}
```

Comment: I am not using Box2D so I don't have a tick method. Should i create one or if not what should I do? Thanks

Comment: do you have a similar method? if not how are you progressing the game?

Comment: I call gameLogic in my init method every .75 seconds.

Comment: so unschedule that:`[gamescene unschedule:@selector(gameLogic )];`

Comment: where do I put that line of code? Do I replace it for [gamescene scheduleUpdate]; or do I put it somewhere else in my code?

Comment: you replace [gamescene unschedule:...]

Comment: Ok, I tried that. I did:

    -(void)pause:(id)sender
    {
        if(paused)
        {
            [GamePlay schedule:@selector(gameLogic)];
        }
        else {
            [GamePlay unschedule:@selector(gameLogic)];
        }
        paused =! paused;
    }

But than I get this error: No known class method for selector 'unschedule' (same for 'schedule').  And sorry for the code I'm not sure how to put it nicely in a comment.  Do you know what I need to do to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: GamePlay looks like its a singleton, if that's not the case then you have to reference an actual instance and not the static method.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that?

Comment: What is GamePlay in the example above is it a class or an object?

Comment: I have two files named GamePlay.h and GamePlay.m.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to "pause" the desired layer unless I'm missing something.  Why can't you just disable touches on everything except the pause layer while the pause layer is showing?  It seems that is the end result that you would like anyways?

Comment: What if it animations running on that layer? Rather than response to touches?

Comment: You have a couple of options.  You could set the speed of all running animations to 0 to effectively pause them using CCSpeed then set their speed back to 1 when you un-pause. See cocos2d docs on CCSpeed here http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:actions_ease?s[]=ccspeed#speed_action or you could stop the animations all together and start them again later.

Comment: @JamesWebster is correct.  I have animation on my game layer that I want to pause, both pause the touches and the animations, however I want to keep the touches and animations on the pause layer active so I can interact with it.

Comment: @bagelboy my solution should work for you if I am following correctly and it is one that I've used in several projects.  Certainly there's many ways to approach this so perhaps it's just a personal preference.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I am currently working on something else in my project but I'll come back to this later today or tomorrow and let you know how it goes.  Thanks again